# Can I use AutoIT, running as a service on a server, using the send function

Tags: service, autoit, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to trigger Illustrator javascripts through the use of AutoIT and its send function. AutoIT is invoked via a Perl script and it works when I have Illustrator open and I run the Perl script from the command line. (The Perl script runs in a continuous loop, triggered by files arriving in a hot folder.) It runs on a server when I have an active connection. However, when I disconnect, keeping the session alive, the autoIT process does not work. (I'm guessing it is because I'm using the send function which requires an active window.)

This is running on a Windows 2003 server.

Is this possible to do or am I farting in the wind.

Thanks in advance.

---

CODE:

```
Run("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6\Support     Files\Contents\Windows\Illustrator.exe")

WinActivate("Adobe Illustrator CS6")
sleep (3000)

Send("!f")
Send("{DOWN 17}")
Send("{RIGHT 2}")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: The send function doesn't require an active window, unless you use `winwaitactive`. Could you provide some code of your autoit script ?

Comment: `Send` sends commands to the active window only. Are you sure that Illustrator is still the active window after the disconnect?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Admittedly, I am a newbie with AutoIT and I do appreciate the feedback. The code has been posted and is quite simple. It works like a champ... until I disconnect from the server.

Comment: Found on the AutoIT forum:http://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_doesn.27t_my_script_work_on_a_locked_workstation.3F

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation on the Send() function in AutoIT. Also if you look near the bottom of the page after the key examples you can see that it also recommends trying to use ControlSend: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm